# Sort Listing of search items by Item Path

Tags: content-search

I need to display a list of items based on their path. For instance:

**Content tree setup:**
 [image]

I am trying to sort results by item path, so if I perform a search that matches the items in the below list then the results would display in the following order, regardless of relevance, age, etc.:

- CategoryA
- Book1
- Article1
- CategoryB
- Book2
- Article4

I have tried using `.OrderBy(x => [SearchReturnedItem].Paths.Path).ToArray()`, but it's not working. Does anyone have any suggestions that might help?

*edit - code moved to question body*

```
using (var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("<indexname>").CreateSearchCon‌​text()) 
{ 
    var result = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
      .Where(x => x.TemplateId.Guid.ToString()
      .Contains("<Template1-GUID>,<Tem‌​plate2-GUID>,<Templa‌​te3-GUID>,..>")); 

    var sortedResult = result.OrderBy(x => x.Path); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `OrderBy(x => x.Path)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[SearchReturnedItem].Paths.Path)` is going to to return the list of ItemIDs for the path. You'll want to instead sort by `[SearchReturnedItem].Path` which will sort by the full text path you are looking for.

Comment: Assuming `[SearchReturnedItem]` is a `SearchResultItem` then technically `[SearchReturnedItem].Paths.Path` should result in a compilation error since `SearchResultItem.Paths` is an `IEnumerable<ID>`, but you are correct that what the OP is looking for is `SearchResultItem.Path` :) +1